# arangodb starter mode does not start

Tags: arangodb

I have d/l'd arangodb3-linux-3.9.2 from GIT on Centos 7. I created a database dir and ran the README instructions for a standalone start. The first time it runs, I get 100 failures, the key INFO log lines seem to be

```
... [INFO] server started component=arangodb pid=49827 type=single
... [INFO] Wait on 49827 returned component=arangodb exit-status=1 trap-cause=-1
```

It creates the log file, setup.json and a single8529 dir in the database dir I sped'd. Is it just taking too long to start? The whole 100 fails take about 1 or 2 seconds.

If I try to run it again with the same README instructions, the next time I get this error:

```
... [FATAL] Failed to run service error="open /.../single8529/data/ENGINE: no such file"
```

I have also tried with `--starter.host 127.0.0.1` -- to simplify

Also I and can confirm that port 8529 is open

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get arangodb 'starter' according to their README to work, but this does start the server:

```
arangod --database.directory MYDIR --rocksdb.max-background-jobs 4
```